Handsontable not displaying until I click
I have a handsontable on one of my pages. This works on all of the windows computers I've tested on, but on one mac it doesn't. The top left of the table is showing, but all the rows and columns don't show up until i click the top left of the table.
I've tried adding a Timeout function to see if that would help, but the same problem still happens

Please visit [ask] and then post a [mcve] using the [<>] snippet editor and CDNs. Also what browser on what version of OSX?
